# A good C++ native multimedia library?

Tags: c++, media

Can anyone recommend a portable, c++ native multimedia library? I've tried SDL, but it doesn't interface well with classes, as it is a c library.

Comment: How does the library being written in C make it not interface well with classes?  Many (modern) C libraries have an object-oriented style and fit well into a thin C++ wrapper.

Comment: @AndréCaron Yes but you’d have to *write* that think C++ wrapper, which can be *a lot* of boilerplate code. If such a library already exists (and it does), all the better.

Comment: It must. What's the point in learning multiple libraries for different platforms?

Comment: @tiddlydum So that your app uses each platform to the best of its abilities?

Comment: @quant_dev well, if you've picked a decent portable library (boost), it should already do that for you.

Comment: @tiddlydum I imagine it is a bit easier to write a multi-platform shared pointer class than to stream MPG in a multi-platform way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s [**SFML**](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) – the “Simple and Fast Multimedia Library” – which is essentially a object-oriented, platform-independent, OpenGL-based alternative to SDL and which looks really quite promising.

It allows to write very clear code with no special attention to resource cleanup:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    sf::Image Image;
    if (not Image.LoadFromFile("cute_image.jpg"))
        return -1;
    sf::Sprite Sprite(Image);

    while (App.IsOpened()) {
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.GetEvent(Event)) {
            if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.Close();
        }

        App.Clear();
        App.Draw(Sprite);
        App.Display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org)?

It's very widely used, cross platform, and their site mentions libavcodec which might be a suitable library for you.

Comment: It's a great suggestion, but `ffmpeg` is also written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg is a pretty good library, though not that easy to use.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: ffmpeg isn't free as in freedom, and I don't really want to get bogged down with propriety libraries.

Comment: ffmpeg source is under [LGPL and GPL](http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html) (GPL only for certain components).